# How can I disable past dates in my datepicker?

Tags: jquery

How can i disable my past date from the current date. I check already the other threads but its not working in my codes.

```
<script>
$("#checkinDate").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startView: "month",
        minView: "month",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true
});
$("#checkoutDate").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startView: "month",
        minView: "month",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list error is like that

Comment: which version of jquery you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<script>
$("#checkinDate").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startView: "month",
        minView: "month",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        minDate:new Date()
});
$("#checkoutDate").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startView: "month",
        minView: "month",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        minDate:new Date()
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sir my datepicker doesnt open when i use that.

Comment: can you please check in console what error are you getting. you can try this also `minDate: today`

Comment: it has error SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: Please solve your syntax error. then check it will work

Comment: thanks sir! may i should just chance my datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minDate:new Date()`. this will disable past date.

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_patidar/2pu9gtv4/

Answer (score -1):

Apply below

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
           
            maxDate: '0',
           
         });
```